# Checking if a table has more than one row VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a document in word using VBA. I have made a table inside a rich text content control and also have made a button which can be pressed to open up a user form.
The problem I am facing is every time I run the code it replaces the table within the rich text control. I wanted to know if there is a 'if' function to say if there is more than one row in the table then do something else? The code I have to make the table is

```
Sub TableCRT()
Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlRichText)
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:= _
    4, defaulttablebehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
    wdAutoFitFixed
    
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1)
    .Cells(1).Range.Text = "heading 1"
    .Cells(2).Range.Text = "heading 2"
    .Cells(3).Range.Text = "heading 3"
    .Cells(4).Range.Text = "heading 4"
End With
End Sub
```

I have also tried

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Count < 0 Then
    Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlRichText)
    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:= _
    4, defaulttablebehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
    wdAutoFitFixed
    
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1)
        .Cells(1).Range.Text = "heading 1"
        .Cells(2).Range.Text = "heading 2"
        .Cells(3).Range.Text = "heading 3"
        .Cells(4).Range.Text = "heading 4"
    End With
    Dim Form As Object
    Set Form = UserForm1
    Form.Show
Else
    Dim Form As Object
    Set Form = UserForm1
    Form.Show
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll want to rewrite your code, starting it with a test to see if the content control exists, followed by a test to see if it contains a table. If both of those tests fail, then you would run your existing code to create a content control and add a table to it. Is the content control the only one that will be added to the document? Is the table you add going to be the only table in the document?

Comment: It should be the only content control and the only table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code checks if the number of content controls and tables are 0 before trying to add them. Declaring a table variable and setting the added table to that variable makes it easier to refer to the table and modify it later. Finally, if the table has more than one row, you can replace the MsgBox line with whatever processing you want to happen:

```
Sub TableCRT()
    Dim oTable As Table

    If ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Count = 0 Then
        Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlRichText)
    End If
    If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count = 0 Then
        Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:= _
            4, defaulttablebehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
            wdAutoFitFixed)
            
        With oTable.Rows(1)
            .Cells(1).Range.Text = "heading 1"
            .Cells(2).Range.Text = "heading 2"
            .Cells(3).Range.Text = "heading 3"
            .Cells(4).Range.Text = "heading 4"
        End With
    Else
        Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    End If
    If oTable.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Hello"
        'Do something here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi John, this seems like it should work but an error pops up saying 'Rich text controls cannot be applied here'. Any suggestions? **edit** I think its to do with because it is trying to put it in the position of where the cursor is and obviously that is the button that I am clicking.

Comment: I added a rich text box before running the code which seemed to get rid of the error, but now is showing another one! 'This method or property is not available because the object refers to a drawing object'. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can only test here with a blank document, as you haven't shared your file. I see no such error message here.

Answer (score 0):

You add every time a ContentControll but you allways refer to the first table in the document.

Try something like this

```
Dim g As ContentControl
Dim t As Table
Set g = Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
Set t = g.Range.Tables.Add(g.Range, 1, 4) ' change this to your code
With t.Rows(1)
.Cells(1).Range.Text = "heading 1"
.Cells(2).Range.Text = "heading 2"
.Cells(3).Range.Text = "heading 3"
.Cells(4).Range.Text = "heading 4"
End With
```